# do spaces in sql tables fubar queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having an issue I'm generating sudoku puzzles and the solution to the puzzle are being stored in this format: 
xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx

8 spaces between the 9 sets, I cannot seem to query the row, it returns a blank row..

Is this because there is spaces? If I do a select where solution like 'xxxxxxxxx%'
then the row returns properly..

Did I just generate 50,000 rows for nothing :( If so how should I fix this spacing problem?

edit here is the query:

```
select * from sudoktion_puzzles 
where
p_solution='582917643 467283195 391546278 159362784 
674851329 823794561 216438957 938675412 745129836'
```

Comment: Can you include the query that isn't working?  That might help us figure this out...

Comment: Never had spaces do that.  Perhaps a bit more for us?

Comment: Can you please give us a full script which reproduces the problem: CREATE TABLE, INSERT and SELECT which fails.  I think you've got a table name wrong or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys those spaces were actually newline/enter characters this fixed it:

```
UPDATE sudoktion_puzzles
SET p_board = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(p_board, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
```

Answer (score 4):

In the query you quoted, you have two spaces before the second-to-last term (the one beginning with '9').  If that's your actual query code but not the actual value in the table, it would explain your problem.

Comment: Argh!  I lost being first by 13 seconds!

Yup, that's what I saw.  Remove the second space and I'll bet the query will work.

Comment: Sorry guys thats not the actual query SO code snipplet is being weird there's only one space infront of the second to last term!

Answer (score 1):

About the only thing peculiar about spaces you really need to remember about SQL Server (ANSI compliant) is that **trailing** spaces are not factored into `LEN()` or equality comparisons.

Is there anything peculiar about your data types?

Are they long enough to hold the entire string (at least 89 characters)?

If you want to get rid of the spaces, you can simply remove the spaces with:

```
UPDATE sudoktion_puzzles
SET p_solution = REPLACE(p_solution, ' ', '')
```

Comment: fixed the query snipplet the query is actually one space before the last term, still returns blank results

Comment: I've gotten rid of all white space and it still returns blanks, my p_solution is a varchar(max)

Comment: Don't use varchar(max) for a column like this.

Comment: would you suggestion varchar(89)?

Comment: I'd actually suggest char(89) since they will all be the same.  There's no savings to be had choosing varchar(89).  And they don't vary.

Comment: That probably isn't your problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that there isn't a second space anywhere, before or after.

Run

```
SELECT * FROM sudoktion_puzzles
 WHERE LEN(p_solution) <> 89
```

and see if you return the row you can't get otherwise.  If so then you have extra spaces.

Comment: Could it be some type of implicit type conversion?  Perhaps your string of 81 digits are being interpreted as a number?

(Just guessing at this point.)

Comment: I'm almost about to blame godaddy's crappy sql server.. :/ The query Cade gave me doesn't seem to be replacing whitespace